# Push single key with multiple values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object array with the following structure:

```
{id: 'TestId', name: 'TestNameString', type: 'TestType' }, ...
```

I want to restructure the following format so that the id is the key:

```
TestId : { name: 'TestNameString', type: 'TestType' }
```

And then push them into an array.

I cant find a way to do so, so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that isn't pseudocode. Give us a precise input and output and someone will probably answer you in a short time (e.g., `x => x.map(({id, ...rest})=>({[id]: rest}))`?) Right now there's not enough info to answer.

Comment: Please show us an example of the expected output, include 2 or 3 records please.  You say "push them into an array" but you can't do that with an object property, so you maybe meant "add them to an object" but I'm not sure.

Comment: You've accepted an answer but you still have not [edit]ed the question to specify what you want exactly.  Please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` and object destructuring.

```js
const arr = [{id: 'TestId', name: 'TestNameString', type: 'TestType' }];
const res = arr.map(({id, ...rest}) => ({[id]: rest}));
console.log(res);
```